# get this error after compiling code "ionic cordova run android"

Tags: cordova, ionic3

ionic 3, cordova plug-in code I wrote with "ionic cordova run android" command after I get this error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfk9R.png)

Answer (score 0):

C://Users/User/App/platforms/android/build.gradle

dependencies {

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0' }
```

change

dependencies {

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'}
```

this problem solved.